# Why os.path.dirname(__file__) is working in Django?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

Please explain why `os.path.dirname(__file__)` is working in Django, but not working in python?
This is kind of weird situation which I can't understand.

I made a python script and put it in a file test_file.py:

```
import os

dirname = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
realpath = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
abspath = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

print dirname
print realpath
print abspath
```

When I run the script, I get results:

```
(env)user@ubuntubox:~/srv/django_pro$ python test_file.py 

/home/srv/django_pro
/home/srv/django_pro
(env)user@ubuntubox:~/srv/django_pro$
```

I get results that **realpath** and **abspath** are working, but **dirname** is empty. However in Django settings.py I have:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

If I go into python shell and print out BASE_DIR, it is not empty:

```
(env)user@ubuntubox:~/srv/django_pro$ python manage.py shell
Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> from django.conf import settings
>>> 
>>> print 'BASE_DIR:\n%s' % settings.BASE_DIR
BASE_DIR:
/home/srv/django_pro
>>>
```

And that means os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(**file**)) is not empty. I am using same python in both cases. And my Django version is:

```
Django==1.7b4
```

So what is the trick?

Comment: Working in Django but not in python?? What does that even mean?

Comment: Yes. Working in Django but not in Python.

Comment: @Martijin Pieters is here. Everything will be OK now :-) My every problem in Python was answered by him :-)

Comment: Django *is* Python. "Working in Django but not in Python" is a completely nonsensical thing to say.

Comment: To be honest, I was reading those answers and I didn't find this is a duplicate question. I believe for many python beginers such question might appear. It's pitty it is marked as duplicated, but thanks for the answer. I will accept it when I can.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first *script* that you run has `__file__` set to the *path you passed to Python*. You started the script with `python test_file.py` so `__file__` is set to `'test_file.py'`. Had you used `python /home/srv/django_pro/test_file.py` your test script would have shown a path for all three options.

Imported modules, on the other hand, have their `__file__` value set to the *full path*.

You need to take this into account and *always* use `os.path.abspath`:

```
directory = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
```

Comment: Thanks @Martijn Pieters for the answer. So the trick was that imported modules has their __file__ value set to the full path. OK, good to know.
I ran the script with full path and so got the answer:

    ***/home/srv***,
    ***/home/srv/django_pro***,
    ***/home/srv/django_pro***.

I will use os.path.abspath(__file__) in Django from now.

Comment: `os.path.abspath` seems redundant to me in the code above, since as you said, inside a module the absolute path is returned anyway.

Comment: @h4k1m: but *not in a script*. The point being that this code can be used either way.